# Adding 30 seconds to NSDate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, uilocalnotification, date-arithmetic

How can I convert an `NSDate` to seconds? I need it in seconds so that I can added 30 secs to the date and then convert back to `NSDate` to schedule a local notification. Any better ways of doing that are welcome too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `dateByAddingTimeInterval` and pass in the value as 30. This will return you an `NSDate` which will be 30 secs ahead.

```
NSDate *newDate = [previousDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:30];
```

Answer (score -1):

[Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1) states that [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003642) should be used to perform date calculations.

Quote from the same document:

> You should use the provided methods for dealing with calendrical calculations because they take into account corner cases like daylight savings time starting or ending and leap years.

So to add 30 seconds to a date, you should do something like this:

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar * currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];

[dateComponents setSecond:30];

NSDate * newDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:date options:0];

NSLog(@"%@", newDate);
```